# How to Use a Single Custom Error Page for all 404 Requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have created a custom 404 page for resources that dont exist.

It works with all endpoints except the ones which have `/api/v1/`, where I get the default NGINX 404 page.

I have `domain.name.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;

    root /var/www/domain.name/public_html;
    error_page 404 /not_found.html;

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        limit_except GET HEAD { deny all; }
    }

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /not_found.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

On adding the `$try_files` directive inside `/api/v1/`, "Hello, World!" from the backend REST API is not displayed at `/api/v1/hello`, even though its a valid endpoint. Instead I get the custom 404 error page:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;

    root /var/www/domain.name/public_html;
    error_page 404 /not_found.html;

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        try_files $uri =404;
        limit_except GET HEAD { deny all; }
    }

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /not_found.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

How can I use a single custom error page for all non existing resources ?

Comment: Set [`proxy_intercept_errors on`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) to process responses from the proxy with your `error_code` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Smith's comment, the `conf` file look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;

    root /var/www/domain.name/public_html;
    error_page 404 /not_found.html;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        limit_except GET HEAD { deny all; }
    }

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /not_found.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```